# Can't open emotion component settings after update to Shopware 5.2.20

Tags: javascript, extjs, e-commerce, shopware

I've built a custom emotion component for shopping worlds in Shopware 5.1.6 which works as intended. However, after upgrading to Shopware 5.2.20 I can't open the settings of the element in the shopping world designer. I get the following error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined
    at Object.parseNamespace (ext-all.js?201702271540:21)
    at Object.get (ext-all.js?201702271540:21)
    at Object.instantiate (ext-all.js?201702271540:21)
    at Object.instantiateByAlias (ext-all.js?201702271540:21)
    at Object.widget (ext-all.js?201702271540:21)
    at i.create (ext-all.js?201702271540:21)
    at i.lookupComponent (ext-all.js?201702271540:21)
    at i.prepareItems (ext-all.js?201702271540:21)
    at i.add (ext-all.js?201702271540:21)
    at initItems (ext-all.js?201702271540:21)
```

Other users reported (in the Shopware forum) that the Javascript file has to start with a comment and that the filename isn't allowed to contain the `-` character. My file fulfills both requirements.

I don't really know what to do at this point. I couldn't find any other relevant posts and the error message just doesn't make any sense to me. Does someone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: You may want to remove everything about shopware from your question and provide us with an ExtJS version and your ExtJS source code that exhibits the problem. Especially the names of your component - the full qualified name and the widget alias AKA xtype. This definitely is an ExtJS-only problem. The version seems to be 4.x or earlier, and the issue seems to be that the namespace or part of the namespace is an empty string, but in the versions I checked, empty strings are caught with a human-readable error message earlier in the stack trace.

Comment: @Alexander thank you for your comment. My plugin works again, but I'm not sure why. I changed the line `me.callParent(arguments);` to `me.callSuper(arguments);` which didn't work. I changed it back to `me.callParent(arguments);` and now it works.